# returning angular promise from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

```
app.factory('myService', ["$http",function($http){
      this.test = function(){
      return $http.post('fooBar.com');
    }
}

app.controller('myController' ['myService',function(mySerivce){
    myService.test().then(function(){ console.log("success");});
}]);
```

My issue is, when I call `myService.test()` in `myController`. Success is never being outputted to the console. What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: do you get any errors in console? what happens if you fix the typos?

Comment: no errors after I fix the typos

Comment: Check your console and verify the request is going thru

Comment: try `myService.test().then(function(){ console.log("success");}, function(){ console.log("error"); })`. Is "error" displayed ?

Comment: thank you, my post was erroring out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following block of code contains an error

`myService.test().then(function() console.log("success"););`

This is the correction. You were missing the `{}` to wrap the contents of your function inside `then()`

`myService.test().then(function() { console.log("success"); } );`

#### Edit (from comments)

Add `.catch()` to your promise chain so any errors/failures are acknowledged and handled by the `$http.post()` promise chain.

```
myService.test()
    .then(function() { 
      console.log("success"); 
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('failure');
    });
```

Comment: @gh9 your service is defined as `mySerivce` in your question but you're injecting it as `myService` is this also a typo? Otherwise that's another problem in your code.

Comment: You also have service spelled wrong when you create it. 

app.factory('mySerivce'

Comment: @gh9 are you sure that its definitely succeeding? You're not using `.catch()` so even if it is failing you're not acknowledging and handling that failure. Add `.catch()` to your promise chain and see if that helps.

Comment: @gh9 glad that you were able to solve this by adding the `.catch()`. I'm going to add this to my answer.